# Partition a number into a given set of numbers

Tags: python, numbers, set, partition

Here is what I am trying to do. Given a number and a set of numbers, I want to partition that number into the numbers given in the set (with repetitions).
For example :
take the number 9, and the set of numbers = {1, 4, 9}. 
It will yield the following partitions :

{ (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4), (1, 4, 4), (9,)}

No other possible partitions using the set {1, 4, 9} cannot be formed to sum the number 9.

I wrote a function in Python which do the task :

```
S = [ 1, 4, 9, 16 ]
def partition_nr_into_given_set_of_nrs(nr , S):
   lst = set()
   # Build the base case :
   M = [1]*(nr%S[0]) + [S[0]] * (nr //S[0])
   if set(M).difference(S) == 0  :
      lst.add(M)
   else :
      for x in S :
         for j in range(1, len(M)+1):
            for k in range(1, nr//x +1 ) :
               if  k*x ==  sum(M[:j]) :
                  lst.add(  tuple(sorted([x]*k + M[j:])) )
   return lst
```

It works correctly but I want to see some opinions about it. I'm not satisfied about the fact that it uses 3 loops and I guess that it can be improved in a more elegant way. Maybe recursion is more suited in this case. Any suggestions or corrections would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 16 in `S` is correct?

Comment: Yes, because it will ignore it as it is bigger than 9, the number to partition. The function works well with or without it. The larger numbers cannot be part of a partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this using a recursive function, starting with the largest number and recursively finding solutions for the remaining value, using smaller and smaller numbers.

```
def partition_nr_into_given_set_of_nrs(nr, S):
    nrs = sorted(S, reverse=True)
    def inner(n, i):
        if n == 0:
            yield []
        for k in range(i, len(nrs)):
            if nrs[k] <= n:
                for rest in inner(n - nrs[k], k):
                    yield [nrs[k]] + rest
    return list(inner(nr, 0))

S = [ 1, 4, 9, 16 ]
print(partition_nr_into_given_set_of_nrs(9, S))
# [[9], [4, 4, 1], [4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Of course you could also do without the inner function by changing the parameters of the function and assuming that the list is already sorted in reverse order.

If you want to limit the number of parts for large numbers, you can add an aditional parameter indicating the remaining allowed number of elements and only yield result if that number is still greater than zero.

```
def partition_nr_into_given_set_of_nrs(nr, S, m=10):
    nrs = sorted(S, reverse=True)
    def inner(n, i, m):
        if m > 0:
            if n == 0:
                yield []
            for k in range(i, len(nrs)):
                if nrs[k] <= n:
                    for rest in inner(n - nrs[k], k, m - 1):
                        yield [nrs[k]] + rest
    return list(inner(nr, 0, m))
```

Comment: Hi Tobias_k. What If I want to have an up limit for the number of elements in the list ? For example : I can't use the function for : nr =1000 and a set S ={1, 4, 9, 16,25, 36,49, 64,81} .  Obviously is too much, the code freezes. But I want to limit the number of elements of resulting partitions to 10 let's say.  This is achievable. Then how this can be done ? Many Thanks.

Comment: @youth4ever See my edit. Note, however, that for your example input there seems to be no solution with just 10 terms.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `itertools` and has two for loops so time complexity is about O(n*n) (roughly)

A little memoization applied to reshape list by removing any element that is greater than max sum needed.

Assuming you are taking sum to be max of your set (9 in this case).

**sourceCode**

```
import itertools

x = [ 1, 4, 9, 16 ]
s = []
n = 9
#Remove elements >9
x = [ i for i in x if i <= n]

for i in xrange(1,n + 1):
    for j in itertools.product(x,repeat = i):
        if sum(j) == n:
            s.append(list(j))

#Sort each combo
s =[sorted(i) for i in s]
#group by unique combo
print list(k for k,_ in itertools.groupby(s))
```

**Result**

```
>>> 
>>> 
[[9], [1, 4, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

**EDIT**

You can further optimize speed (if needed) by stopping finding combo's after sum of product is `> 9`
e.g.

```
if sum(j) > n + 2:
            break
```